# How do I do a Left join in a rails find

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, join

I have this

```
User.joins(:notifications).joins(:company_users).joins(:role_users).where("notifications.id = ? AND role_users.role_id != '1' AND (company_users.company_id = ? OR users.company_id = ?)", notification.id, p.company_id, p.company_id)
```

=> []

which produces this sql

```
SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` 
INNER JOIN `subscriptions` ON `users`.`id` = `subscriptions`.`user_id` 
INNER JOIN `notifications` ON `notifications`.`id` = `subscriptions`.`notification_id` 
INNER JOIN `company_users` ON `company_users`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` 
INNER JOIN `role_users` ON `role_users`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` 
WHERE (notifications.id = 1 
AND role_users.role_id != '1' 
AND (company_users.compcany_id = 67 OR users.company_id = 67))
```

the problem is I need to left join on company_users and not sure how to achieve that in rails

I know I can do this with find_by_sql by i heard thats not really rails like....any ideas

Comment: Do you have a `has_one :company_user` or `has_many :company_users` association?

Comment: I solved it ...look at my answer...and to answer your question its a many to many though company_user

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Solved

```
User.joins(:notifications).joins("LEFT JOIN `company_users` ON `company_users`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`").joins(:role_users).where("notifications.id = ? AND role_users.role_id != '1' AND (company_users.company_id = ? OR users.company_id = ?)", notification.id, p.company_id, p.company_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

class User < ActiveRecord::Base

```
 has_many :friends, :foreign_key=>"u_from",:class_name=>"Friend"
```

end

class Friend < ActiveRecord::Base

```
 belongs_to :user
```

end

friends = user.friends.where(:u_req_status=>2).joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN users ON users.u_id = friends.u_to").select("friend_id,u_from,u_to,u_first_name,u_last_name,u_email,u_fbid,u_twtid,u_picture_url,u_quote")