# Convert Inner Join to Left Join in rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, join

I have a rake file , and i have this code on it . .

```
   if circle[:conference2_total_channels].present?
                conf = Confbridge.find(:all, :conditions => ["confbridges.cid = ?",circle.circle_number],
                :joins => [:confbridge_participants],
                :select => 'confbridges.id, confbridges.confno, confbridges.max_member, (confbridges.max_member - 5) AS additional , (confbridges.max_member - IFNULL(confbridge_participants.active,0)) AS vacant')

            end
```

the return of the code is

```
SELECT confbridges.id, confbridges.confno, confbridges.max_member, (confbridges.max_member - 5) AS additional , (confbridges.max_member - IFNULL(confbridge_participants.active,0)) AS vacant FROM `confbridges` **INNER JOIN** `confbridge_participants` ON `confbridge_participants`.`confbridge_id` = `confbridges`.`id` WHERE (confbridges.cid = '0090000092')
```

it is **INNER JOIN**

how can i change it to **LEFT JOIN**

like this

```
SELECT confbridges.id, confbridges.confno, confbridges.max_member, (confbridges.max_member - 5) AS additional , (confbridges.max_member - IFNULL(confbridge_participants.active,0)) AS vacant FROM `confbridges` **LEFT JOIN** `confbridge_participants` ON `confbridge_participants`.`confbridge_id` = `confbridges`.`id` WHERE (confbridges.cid = '0090000092')
```

THANKS :)

Comment: What version of rails do you use? This syntax was deprecated somewhere in the 3rd

Comment: Seems like you are using a very old version of Rails. Aren't you?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I do a Left join in a rails find](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10722106/how-do-i-do-a-left-join-in-a-rails-find)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would write it:

```
Confbridge.where("confbridges.cid = ?",circle.circle_number)
  .joins("LEFT JOIN confbridge_participants 
         ON confbridge_participants.confbridge_id = confbridges.id")
  .select(...your select statement)
```

Comment: definitely works. I was hoping personally that there would be a syntax along the lines of `.joins(:left, [:my, :associations])`